# Generating variable

Tags: stata

I have a dataset in which variables are like the image

[image: Variables in dataset]

I want to produce a table for serogroup and all antibiotics[penicillin-tetracycline]. Antibiotics have value label `("Sensitive" "Resistant")`.

Here I only consider "Resistant" value.

I have tried following code:

```
gen All_antibiotic =1 if penicillin=="Resistant"
replace All_antibiotic =2 if ampicillin=="Resistant"
.
.
tab All_antibiotic serogroup
```

But it did not give complete table.

Comment: Why did you reverse edits? You removed improvements to your English and to presentation of code. It would have been better to improve the question along the lines implied by the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing explains about editing.

Answer (score 1):

There are various difficulties here:

1. You don't provide a reproducible example, in that you don't provide a data example we can use. See [this page on minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. You don't make clear what would be the rows, columns and cells of the table.
3. You are confusing string values and value labels. `"Resistant"` is a string value, not a value label.
4. The question title doesn't really indicate the problem.

This may help. In your case you would need `rename` before you could use `reshape`.

```
clear 
input id group str4(y1 y2 y3) 
1 1   frog frog toad 
2 1   frog toad toad  
3 1   toad toad toad 
4 2   frog frog frog 
5 2   frog frog toad 
6 2   frog toad toad 
end 
preserve 
reshape long y, i(id) j(which) 
describe 
tab group y 

           |           y
     group |      frog       toad |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         1 |         3          6 |         9 
         2 |         6          3 |         9 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |         9          9 |        18 

restore
```